# Generated header not found

Tags: c++, bazel, flatbuffers

I'm trying to use Bazel to build a cpp project that use Flatbuffers.
But my `map_schema_generated.h` generated with `flatc` is not found.

My tree:

```
|
|_ data
|  |_ maps
|     |_ BUILD
|     |_ map_schema.fbs
|
|_ src
|  |_ map
|     |_ BUILD
|     |_ map.hpp
|     |_ map.cpp
|
|_ tools
|  |_ BUILD
|  |_ generate_fbs.bzl
|
|_ WORKSPACE
```

`tools/generate_fbs.bzl`:

```
def _impl(ctx):
  output = ctx.outputs.out
  input = ctx.files.srcs
  print("generating", output.basename)
  ctx.action(
      use_default_shell_env = True,
      outputs = [output],
      inputs = input,
      progress_message="Generating %s with %s" % (output.path, input[0].path),
      command="flatc -o %s --cpp %s" % (output.dirname, input[0].path)
  )

generate_fbs = rule(
  implementation=_impl,
  output_to_genfiles = True,
  attrs={
       "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=True, allow_empty=False),
       "out": attr.output()
       },
)
```

`data/maps/BUILD`:

```
load("//tools:generate_fbs.bzl", "generate_fbs")

generate_fbs(
  name = "schema",
  srcs = ["map_schema.fbs"],
  out = "map_schema_generated.h",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

`src/map/BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
  name = "map",
  srcs = [
    "//data/maps:map_schema_generated.h",
    "map.hpp",
    "map.cpp"
  ]
)
```

`src/map/map.cc` has `#include "map_schema_generated.h"`.

The command line I use to build: `bazel build //src/map`.

If I `find` in `bazel-*`,  I got:

```
bazel-genfiles/data/maps/map_schema_generated.h
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles/data/maps/map_schema_generated.h
bazel-my-workspace-name/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/genfiles/data/maps/map_schema_generated.h
```

And if I `cat` these files, I can see that they are well generated.

All the information that I found are about `Tensorflow`, and are not really helpful.

Best regards,

Comment: Not that familiar with Bazel, but given that it builds and generates the files, the problem must be that your `cc_library` defines the header as a dependency, but it does not specify it as an include / include dir. I'd see if there's a way to see the compiler command line generated, and if there's not a `-I` to the generated files dir in there, then that's your problem.

Comment: Ok `bazel build -s //src/map` prints the compiler options. `-I` was missing.
So I add `copts = ["-I$(GENDIR)/data/maps"]` into `src/map/BUILD` and it works.

Thank you for you advice.

(But I don't think that it is the good way)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `cc_library` actually doesn't really recognize your generated header as requiring any special action (like adding `-I` flag for the location it's in). It gets generate and lives in the build tree, but not anywhere the compiler (preprocessor) would look for it working on `map.cpp`. (Run build with `-s` for a bit more insight about what and how happened).

Now about how to address this, there might be a better way, but this would appear to work. I guess this functionality could also be rolled into `generate_fbs` rule.

In `data/maps/BUILD` I've added "header only" library as follows:

```
cc_library(
  name = "map_schema_hdr",
  hdrs = [":map_schema_generated.h"],
  include_prefix = ".",  # to manipulate -I of dependenices
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

In `src/map/BUILD` I would then use this header only library as dependency of `map`:

```
cc_library(
  name = "map",
  srcs = [
    "map.cpp"
    "map.hpp"
  ],
  deps = [
     "//data/maps:map_schema_hdr",
  ]
)
```

---

To play a bit more with the idea of having a single rule (macro) for convenience, I've made the following changes:

`tools/generate_fbs.bzl` now reads:

```
def _impl(ctx):
  output = ctx.outputs.out
  input = ctx.files.srcs
  print("generating", output.basename)
  ctx.action(
      use_default_shell_env = True,
      outputs = [output],
      inputs = input,
      progress_message="Generating %s with %s" % (output.path, input[0].path),
      command="/bin/cp %s %s" % (input[0].path, output.path)
  )

_generate_fbs = rule(
  implementation=_impl,
  output_to_genfiles = True,
  attrs={
       "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=True, allow_empty=False),
       "out": attr.output()
       },
)


def generate_fbs(name, srcs, out):
  _generate_fbs(
    name = "_%s" % name,
     srcs = srcs,
     out = out
  )

  native.cc_library(
    name = name,
    hdrs = [out],
    include_prefix = ".",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  )
```

With that, I could have `data/maps/BUILD`:

```
load("//tools:generate_fbs.bzl", "generate_fbs")

generate_fbs(
  name = "schema",
  srcs = ["map_schema.fbs"],
  out = "map_schema_generated.h",
)
```

And `src/map/BUILD` contains:

```
cc_library(
  name = "map",
  srcs = [
    "map.cpp",
    "map.hpp",
  ],
  deps = [
     "//data/maps:schema",
  ]
)
```

And `bazel build //src/map` builds `bazel-bin/src/map/libmap.a` and `bazel-bin/src/map/libmap.so`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `#include "map_schema_generated.h"` in `src/map/map.cpp`, I could have write `#include "data/maps/map_schema_generated.h".

I think it is the cleanest way to make it works.